# Instantiating an anonymous type returns null

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I'm having a problem instantiating an anonymous type in my code.

For some reason, `TResponse response = default(TResponse);` returns `null`, even though `TResponse` has a constructor for it.

Am I being dumb?!

**Class:**

```
public class MyClass
{
  public MyResponse GetResponse(MyRequest request)
  {
    return Service<MyRequest, MyResponse>.MakeRequest(
      request,
      delegate() {
        return AnotherService.GetRequest(request);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**Service class**

```
public static class Service<TRequest, TResponse>
  where TRequest : IRequest
  where TResponse : IResponse
{
  public delegate TResponse UseDelegate();

  public TResponse MakeRequest(TRequest request, UseDelegate codeBlock)
  {
    TResponse response = default(TResponse); // <-- Returns nulll

    response = codeBlock();

    return response;
  }
}
```

Comment: You've jumped to conclusions by thinking this has anything to do with anonymous types. You could have confirmed that by substituting some other type that you *know* has a name.

Comment: Well, it's anonymous as far as I don't know what type it is. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Brandon has said, `default` returns `null` for any reference type.

However, I don't see why you're using it at all - the value you've assigned will be overwritten by the return value of `codeBlock()` anyway. In other words, you can change your MakeRequest method to just:

```
public TResponse MakeRequest(TRequest request, UseDelegate codeBlock)
{
    TResponse response = codeBlock();
    return response;
}
```

or even:

```
public TResponse MakeRequest(TRequest request, UseDelegate codeBlock)
{
    return codeBlock();
}
```

I'm assuming that in reality there's some more code there... but if you *really* want to call a parameterless constructor, you can constrain TResponse with:

```
where TResponse : IResponse, new()
```

and then use:

```
TResponse response = new TResponse();
```

That way you'll get a compile-time guarantee that `TResponse` has a parameterless constructor; just using `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TResponse))` without a constraint on `TResponse` would work, but would delay finding out about the problem where you tried to use response type which didn't have a parameterless constructor.

Furthermore, I don't see any anonymous types in your code - the only way an anonymous type would have a parameterless constructor would be if you used:

```
new {}
```

which would be somewhat pointless.

Comment: Jon, you are right. There is some logic before the codeblock, but essentially, if I don't add the constructor, then I get problems with using unassigned variables.

Comment: Jon, thanks for enlightening me. I wasn't aware of the use new().

Answer (score 4):

default(T) does not call type T's default constructor like one might think. default(T) means null for classes, 0 for primitives, and a value with all fields initialized to null or 0 for structs.

see keyword [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For complex types, use the [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd.aspx)

So in your example: `TResponse response = Activator.CreateInstance<TResponse>();`

Comment: Or you could just specify the generic type parameter as `where TResponse : IResponse, new()`, and then do `TResponse response = new TResponse();`

Answer (score 1):

you should use new() constraint, and you code will look like this

```
public static class Service<TRequest, TResponse>
  where TRequest : IRequest
  where TResponse : IResponse, new()
{
  public delegate TResponse UseDelegate();

  public TResponse MakeRequest(TRequest request, UseDelegate codeBlock)
  {
    TResponse response = new TResponse();
    response = codeBlock();

    return response;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to create a new instance of a type parameter you should use the new() generic constrait [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5(VS.80).aspx).